# SharePoint 2013 site Certificate invoked error?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, certificate

I had a SP2013 site with claims based authentication, the site uses a certificate which is installed on the SP server, Binding is done, the site runs on https by default, no AAM.  Everything was working fine for a couple of months, but now when I try to access the site I get the error saying that the certificate is invoked. [image]

Chrome
[image]

Internet Explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couple of things to check.

1. Make Sure the certificate is not expired. If it is expired then it will throws the error.
2. Add the SSL cert into the SharePoint trust.goto -  Central admin > security > Manage Trust, upload the SSL certs and test it.
3. Check if the Server has access to internet.
4. Check this [forum post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/46c8bf9f-97ea-498c-b153-eeca9cafa716/how-to-prevent-there-is-a-problem-with-this-websites-security-certificate-error?forum=winserversecurity)